# Can anyone see my Tumblr username if I post from a "sub-tumblr"?

Tags: tumblr

My main blog on Tumblr is `username.tumblr.com`. I follow people, browse the dashboard, and heart posts from that username.

When I post things to a sub-tumblr called `subtumblr.tumblr.com`, on *that tumblr's* 'dashboard' thingy - that is, `tumblr.com/blog/subtumblr` - posts have my `username` avatar next to them. Posts on my regular dashboard, and `subtumblr`'s followers' dashboards, have the `subtumblr` avatar next to them, and link to the subtumblr, unless I check this box:

[image: show author portraits]

<sub>This is on the individual sub-tumblr's settings `http://www.tumblr.com/blog/subtumblr/settings` or similar.</sub>

With that box un-checked, it seems to me that `username` will not be revealed to anyone browsing `subtumblr`, either on the dashboard or on `subtumblr.tumblr.com`. Is this correct? Is there any other area where the name of the parent account might be revealed?

Comment: I typed the word "tumblr" so much it has lost most of its meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only other area where it is possible to be seen is in the rss as `dc:creator`. If you disabled "Show author portraits", then you should be fine (you wouldn't even see it in the RSS)

Other places you will see it are http://www.tumblr.com/blog/subtumblr (under div class `class="avatar_and_i"`) but not /dashboard.

Of course if you reblog the subtumblr or like it any way that can raise speculation. Especially if the subtumblr doesn't have a lot of followers.